# TypeError : argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer,not list Python Error

Tags: python, list, cryptography, aes, cbc-mode

I'm coding an AES - ECB 128 bits function :

```
def EncodeAES_ECB(strMessage,tabKey):     
    strMessage = strMessage.encode('utf8')
    bs = AES.block_size
    cipher = AES.new(tabKey, AES.MODE_ECB)
    resData = cipher.encrypt(strMessage)
    return resData
```

I should test my function by printing:

```
print (EncodeAES_ECB("Elements",[161, 216, 149, 60, 177, 180, 108, 234, 176, 12, 149, 45, 255, 157, 80, 136])==b'Z\xf5T\xef\x9f\x8bg\x15\xb3E\xe7&gm\x96\x1d')
```

I have an error which says : TypeError : argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer,not list
Normally, each element of the list is 1 byte,so the key can be 16 bytes.
How do I transorm the list : `[161, 216, 149, 60, 177, 180, 108, 234, 176, 12, 149, 45, 255, 157, 80, 136]` inside the function `EncodeAES_CBC` in a string or a read-only buffer so that each number of the list can be one byte?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please [edit] your question to include the full error traceback to help understand where the problem is ocurring

Comment: I think `AES.new` function takes binary string rather than a list, maybe you can try to convert list to bstring?

Comment: Please  also add what crypto library you are using when you edit your question.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk Alice is using pycryptodome/pycrypto. I recognise the syntax.